# You need to call the 'UsePreview()' method of the Kentico.Web.Mvc.ApplicationBuilder instance at the start of your application's life cycle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, kentico, kentico-12

I am trying to learn developing with Kentico MedioClinic Tutorial. I tried to follow each step accordingly, but I stucked here.

I searched the problem in the caption, first I tried adding

```
    // Registers enabled bundles
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // Dependency injection
    AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();
```

as documentation suggest, but i am getting the same error.

Any suggestions?[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIlbj.png)

EDIT: I tried recommended solutions but they did not fix it. Global.asax and ApplicationConfig as follows:

[Global.asax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9eKu.jpg)

[ApplicationConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsmjt.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Berserker. Could you please post the text of the error you're facing?

Comment: Hey @Berserker, I checked out your edit and you're calling the `builder.UsePreview();` code twice.  Remove it from your App_Start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not registering your Kentico "features".

Add a new .cs file called ApplicationConfig.cs under /App_Start folder.  In there register your features like so:

```
public static void RegisterFeatures(IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    // Enable required Kentico features

    builder.UsePreview();

    builder.UsePageBuilder(new PageBuilderOptions()
    {
        RegisterDefaultSection = true
    });

    builder.UseResourceSharingWithAdministration();

    RegisterPageTemplateFilters();
}

    private static void RegisterPageTemplateFilters()
    {
        //Enabled, This must be last
        //PageBuilderFilters.PageTemplates.Add(new EmptyPageTemplateFilter());

        //Disabled
        PageBuilderFilters.PageTemplates.Add(new NoEmptyPageTemplateFilter());
    }
```

Then in your Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()` add the following line above registering your routes/bundles:

```
ApplicationConfig.RegisterFeatures(ApplicationBuilder.Current);
```

This should resolve the issue you're having.